GCP REST API or Terraform equivalent of "gcloud services vpc-peerings enable-vpc-service-controls"
Consider this CLI:
gcloud services vpc-peerings enable-vpc-service-controls ...

Questions:

What is the GCP REST API method equivalent to that?
What is the Terraform equivalent to that?


For any gcloud command you can append --log-http to have the command enumerate the underlying REST APIs that are called.
Another approach is to browse the service using:

Google's excellent APIs Explorer though this requires more familiarity with the underlying service
Service Networking API;
enableVpcServiceControls

This approach also provides definitions of the request and response (and Operation) types

I was just told by someone that, since Terraform Google Provider v5.35.0 (released in June 2024), the Terraform equivalent is:
# Enable "VPC-SC for Peerings" on the producer network
resource "google_service_networking_vpc_service_controls" "..." {
  network    = ... # My VPC
  service    = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  enabled    = true
}

